# Finding longest repeating element in vector

Tags: r, vector

I would like to find the starting and ending index of consecutive repeating elements which equal "1" in the following vector. The vector has values which can equal "1" or NA.

For example:

```
out2
 [1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
[21] "1" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

The output should look like the following

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1   21
[2,]  27  32
```

Comment: `out2 <- rep(c(1,NA,1,NA),c(21,5,6,8))` would be easier to work with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `rle`:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)

with(rle(x), {
  ok <- !is.na(values)
  ends <- cumsum(lengths)[ok]
  starts <- ends - lengths[ok] + 1
  cbind(starts, ends)
})
```

giving:

```
     starts ends
[1,]      1   21
[2,]     27   32
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rle` to get the run-length encoding, which makes these sorts of "consecutive elements" analyses relatively simple:

```
r <- rle(out2)
cs <- cumsum(r$lengths)
na.omit(cbind(cs[r$values == "1"] - r$length[r$values == "1"] + 1, cs[r$values == "1"]))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   21
# [2,]   27   32
```

`rle` doesn't love `NA` values (each one is encoded as a run of length 1), so you could shed the `na.omit` syntax if you had, for instance, 1 and 2 instead of 1 and NA:

```
out2 <- rep(c(1,2,1,2),c(21,5,6,8))
r <- rle(out2)
cs <- cumsum(r$lengths)
cbind(cs[r$values == 1] - r$length[r$values == 1] + 1, cs[r$values == 1])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   21
# [2,]   27   32
```

Comment: You could put the subsetting at the end, too: `(cs + cbind(1-r$length,0))[!is.na(r$values)&r$values==1,]` and `(cs+cbind(1-r$length,0))[r$values==1,]`

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` on `out2 <- rep(c(1,NA,1,NA),c(21,5,6,8))`

```
spl <- split(seq_along(out2)[out2==1],cumsum(is.na(out2))[out2==1])
sapply(spl, function(x) c(x[1],tail(x,1)))
#      0  5
#[1,]  1 27
#[2,] 21 32
```

Or an `rle` alternative:

```
r <- rle(is.na(out2))
cbind(c(1,head(cumsum(r$l)[r$v],-1)+1),cumsum(r$l)[!r$v])
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1   21
#[2,]   27   32
```